# Remove maximize/minimize window buttons from GNOME 3.18

Tags: gnome, window-buttons

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my computer and I recently installed GNOME 3.18, alongside Unity.

Being used to having the window buttons on the left side, I changed their position with  some command lines I found on the web. The only problem is that by doing so I also added minimize and maximize buttons which I didn't want.

I tried to remove them and although I did it the buttons remained on core apps such as files and maps. I tried out everything I could think of, but the GNOME Tweak Tool doesn't do much and neither do the commands I found on the net.

Does anyone have any idea?